# How to edit a list of subclass objects

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of items of different classes derived from the same class.

The goal: editing any object using a different view

The model:

```
class Paper: Hashable, Equatable {
    var name: String
    var length: Int

    init() {
        name = ""
        length = 0
    }

    init(name: String, length: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.length = length
    }

    static func == (lhs: Paper, rhs: Paper) -> Bool {
        return lhs.length == rhs.length
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(length)
    }
}

class ScientificPaper: Paper {
    var biology: Bool

    override init(name: String, length: Int) {
        biology = false
        super.init(name: name, length: length)
    }
}

class TechnicalPaper: Paper {
    var electronics: Bool

    override init(name: String, length: Int) {
        electronics = false
        super.init(name: name, length: length)
    }
}
```

The main view containing the list.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var papers: [Paper]
    @State private var edit = false
    @State private var selectedPaper = Paper()

    var body: some View {

        let scientificBinding = Binding<ScientificPaper>(
            get: {selectedPaper as! ScientificPaper},
            set: { selectedPaper = $0 }
        )

        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(papers, id: \.self) { paper in
                    HStack {
                        Text(paper.name)
                        Text("\(paper.length)")
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Edit") {
                            selectedPaper = paper
                            edit = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $edit) {
            VStack {
                if selectedPaper is ScientificPaper {
                    ScientificForm(paper: scientificBinding)
                }
                if selectedPaper is TechnicalPaper {
                    TechnicalForm(paper: technicalBinding)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The custom view for each class.

```
struct ScientificForm: View {
    @Binding var paper: ScientificPaper

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Scientific")
            TextField("Name: ", text: $paper.name)
            TextField("Length: ", value: $paper.length, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            TextField("Biology: ", value: $paper.biology, formatter: NumberFormatter())
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TechnicalForm: View {
    @Binding var paper: TechnicalPaper

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Technical")
            TextField("Name: ", text: $paper.name)
            TextField("Length: ", value: $paper.length, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            TextField("Electronics: ", value: $paper.electronics, formatter: NumberFormatter())
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that at run time I get the following:

> Could not cast value of type 'Paper' to 'ScientificPaper'.

maybe because the selectedPaper is already initialized as Paper.

What is the right strategy to edit list items belonging to different classes?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to creating binding in `body`, which calculates on every refresh, so binding is invalid.

The solution is to make binding as computable property, so it is requested only after validation in correct flow.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 (demo is for `scientificBinding` only for simplicity)

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var papers: [Paper]
    @State private var edit = false
    @State private var selectedPaper = Paper()
    
    var scientificBinding: Binding<ScientificPaper> {   // << here !!
        return Binding<ScientificPaper>(
            get: {selectedPaper as! ScientificPaper},
            set: { selectedPaper = $0 }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(papers, id: \.self) { paper in
                    HStack {
                        Text(paper.name)
                        Text("\(paper.length)")
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Edit") {
                            selectedPaper = paper
                            edit = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $edit) {
            VStack {
                if selectedPaper is ScientificPaper {
                    ScientificForm(paper: scientificBinding)
                }
//                if selectedPaper is TechnicalPaper {
//                    TechnicalForm(paper: technicalBinding)
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi. 'The error is due to creating binding in body' that it's the problem. Another option is creating the binding before calling the Form:  let sb = Binding<ScientificPaper> (
                        get: {selectedPaper as! ScientificPaper},
                        set: {selectedPaper = $0}
                    )
                    ScientificForm(paper: sb)